# url alias not working in block page restrictions

Tags: 7, uri, path-aliases

I've create some blocks that I have set up to show on "Only the listed pages".

I had set up a taxonomy with a url alias and added this alias to the list of pages allowed. This was working few weeks ago. The client has come back saying that the blocks have disappeared from the pages and they have.

When I was looking at the block I took it's none aliased url and put that into the list of allowed urls and then the block reappeared.

Has anyone come across this before and if so was there a reason behind it?

Do I now have to go through the site and put the `node/1` etc.. url into the block allowed lists?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this has to do with having multiple URL Alias set up for the same page. To fix the issue I had to remove all URL Alias' that were not being used. The blocks then reappeared on the page.

If some else has an answer to this please post and if it fits better than my conclusion I'll mark it as the answer instead of this.